# Is it allowed to add output of a method into self?

Tags: python, class, self

I have a class with several methods. Outputs of a method are used in other methods. I don't want to pass these variables as input argument to other methods (to make code more simple).
I can add output of this method into self so I have access to these variables in other methods.

But, I want to be sure that it is a standard implementation. I am worried that it may cause unpredictable error.  If you have experience in this regard, please let me know if the following example is a correct implementation or not.

```
class MyClass:
    
    def method_1(self, A):
        return A + 1
        
    def method_2(self):
        return self.B + 10

    def method_3(self, C):
        self.B = self.method_1(C) 
        result = self.method_2()
        return result

z = MyClass()
z.method_3(1)
```

In the above example, I don't need to pass `self.B` into `method_2`. This code works but I want to be sure that it is a standard way.

The real program I working on is complicated, so I made a simple example for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup it is more or less correct but the standard way of doing something like this is having a `__init__()` method and using function annotations.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.B = 0

    def method_1(self, A: int) -> int:
        return A + 1
        
    def method_2(self) -> int:
        return self.B + 10

    def method_3(self, C: int) -> int:
        self.B = self.method_1(C) 
        result = self.method_2()
        return result

z = MyClass()
z.method_3(1)
```

Comment: What do the annotations have to do with the question? I'm not super familiar with all the aspects of typing.

Comment: I think the crucial thing to emphasize here is having a **sensible default** for `self.B`. If there weren't one, this solution wouldn't really work. Although, making `B` a parameter of `__init__()` could work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Where `method_2()` relies on an attribute that may be unset, make it private so that people aren't tempted to use it. For example, what if I did this?

```
>>> z = MyClass()
>>> z.method_2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tmp.py", line 9, in method_2
    return self.B + 10
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'B'
```

For that matter, it's probably best to make the attribute private too. So:

```
class MyClass:
    
    def method_1(self, A):
        return A + 1
        
    def _method_2(self):
        return self._B + 10

    def method_3(self, C):
        self._B = self.method_1(C) 
        result = self._method_2()
        return result
```

---

By the way, where `method_1()` doesn't use `self`, consider making it a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod).